# TSP Sign Hash Session Information

Tags: docusignapi

I need help:
I am trying to implement my signature solution with DocuSign and I get to point 3: "TSP Sign Hash Session Information" I try to sign but it always throws me the same error message: "TSP_EXTERNAL_SIGN_FAILED  :  message :  The document could not be updated" without giving any further details, can someone help me solve this? I'd be very gratefull

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not docusign support.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use the DocuSign TSP API? That API is for Trust Service Providers (Certificate Authorities).

If you want a document signed then the [eSignature REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api) is recommended.

If you really want to use the TSP API, please edit your question to provide more information on what API method you called and what your request object contained.